# Spring Roo (STS) - Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I ran into a problem trying to use Spring-roo in STS ide.
I created a project and added EclipseLink ORM, and that is about it.
In persistence.xml i added all the details for the database connectivity.
When I tried to run the spring project, it failed to show the default jspx page i was expecting.
Here is the error:

```
2012-07-02 10:45:39,411 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in file [/home/ubuntu/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.0.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/wtpwebapps/SpringRooStats/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [/home/ubuntu/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.0.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/wtpwebapps/SpringRooStats/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
```

It is complaining it seems that it needs to create an entity manager, but I think that 
it should not since it should run a project that does not connect to a database and just run a simple jspx page.

Does one need to go thru the whole thing with entities just to run a simple project.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to learn its text formatting features; it's easier for people to reply if your question is well-formatted (esp. code and error messages).

Comment: I've also encountered similar issue though i'm not sure same thing caused it as only part of stack is pasted... My problem was that i've named same domain and model classes without specifying `@Entity(name="")` for both.

Answer (score 2):

Your applicationcontext.xml has a transactionManager defined.  This needs a entity manager. Your would need to remove the transaction manager or add the entity manager.

I'm also not sure why you added the ORM framework if your not going to use it.